# Bootstrap, can't get image to go to rightside of jumbotron

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="landing">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6"><h1>Hey, I'm A Man <br> Thanks for coming</h1></div>
   <div class="col-sm-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="example.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS for Jumbotron** (Not entirely sure if this is reason it's messing up so leaving it here just incase)

```
#landing {
  background-image: url(jumboimg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: -80px;
}
```

Heres what it's coming out as 
https://i.imgur.com/7wXdWeb.png

I'm trying to get it to the right of the text

Comment: It works as expected in codepen: https://codepen.io/unclenorton/pen/pojbygB. However, I can see that you have a `>` character in your heading, which is likely to mess things up (in codepen, it's escaped automatically, so it doesn't affect anything)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I edited it out. It's not in my actual code.

Comment: My bad, as @Rahul mentioned in his answer, there should actually be a closing `</h1>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below code sample, I have tried to replicate same and it works

and yes there was closing `</h1>` missing in the code

```css
#landing {
  background-image: url(https://www.vklalco.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/mumbai_night-800x400.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 800px;
    /* margin-top: -80px; */
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
img.img-responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  
  
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="landing">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6"><h1>Hey, I'm A Man <br> Thanks for coming</h1></div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     
     <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.pentasia.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBdHJKIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--94a7bbc0f18502cae6a97b304f2712e26588fd1e/pentasia-surrey-redhill2.jpg" alt="">
     
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


  <p>This is some text.</p>      
  <p>This is another text.</p>      
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems adding the img css to it fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: ok, If you think this answer help you in some way you can marked this as answer

Answer (score 0):

width 100% will make your image fit to your column

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="example.png" alt="" width="100%">
```